Is it possible to start/stop recording using Open GoPro API?
I've been reading the documentation for the Open GoPro API and I wasn't able to find a way to start recording a new video. Is this intentional? Or maybe I'm just missing something. I'm starting to think that they don't want that capability exposed.  .

the api support different functionality depending on the device model and method of communication (ble, wifi, usb). looking at the http documentation for wifi communication, "set shutter" says start/stop encoding (recording).
